# How to display a running counter in the html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element that contains a numerical value. which corresponds to number of minutes:seconds the current game is played for. I want to make it a running counter showing time of spent trying to solve the game.

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to point you in the right direction before anything else- you'll always learn a lot more if you manage to complete a task yourself (albeit with guidance). If you're still having trouble, just comment and I'll be happy to provide a more code-based answer.

Keep track of two variables: `totalSeconds` and `totalMinutes`. Write a function that executes every second (this can be accomplished using JavaScript's `setInterval` method) that adds 1 to `totalSeconds`- and, if that number reaches 60, adds 1 to `totalMinutes` and resets `totalSeconds` to 0.

i.e., here's what the two variables will contain, modified every second:

```
totalSeconds <- 0
totalMinutes <- 0

totalSeconds <- 1
totalMinutes <- 0

totalSeconds <- 2
totalMinutes <- 0

...

totalSeconds <- 59
totalMinutes <- 0

totalSeconds <- 0
totalMinutes <- 1

totalSeconds <- 1
totalMinutes <- 1

totalSeconds <- 2
totalMinutes <- 1

...
```

After updating those two variables, change the div's `innerHTML` property to represent the changes.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have a functional fiddle you can work from if you'd like:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicholas_eden/zaRqQ/

Html:

```
<span id="elapsed">0:00</span>;​
```

Javascript:
   var $elapsed = $('#elapsed');

```
var start = new Date().getTime();


function updateTime() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsed = now - start;
  var formatted = secondsToTime(elapsed/1000);
  $elapsed.html(formatted.h + ':' + formatted.m + ':' + formatted.s);
  setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
}


function secondsToTime(secs) {
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

  var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

  var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
  var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }

  var obj = {
    "h": hours,
    "m": minutes,
    "s": seconds
  };
  return obj;
}

updateTime();​
```

This takes the approach of getting the initial time, then each second it calculates the difference in the current time and initial time.  Then parses that into a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<div id="countdown" onload="countDown(10:20)"> 10:20 </div>
```

In JS

```
function countDown(time) { 
    cmin2=time.split(":")[0];
    csec2=time.split(":")[1];
    down=setInterval(function(){DownRepeat();},1000);
}

unction DownRepeat() { 
    csec2--;        
    if(csec2==-1) { 
        csec2=59; cmin2--; 
    }

    if ((cmin2 == 0) && (csec2 == 0)) {
         clearInterval(down);
     //do ur action after finish count down
    }   
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = cmin2 + ";" + csec2; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the counter in an Iframe, have the Iframe refresh every half second or second, so the "game" keeps running but the Iframe will show an updated counter every second. (I wouldnt go closer than second)

-S